# CMake delete multiple directories when running make clean using set_directory_properties

Tags: cmake

How do I delete multiple directories using `make clean` when using CMake? I have found the `set_directory_properties` command. This works for a single directory when I do the following:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "foo")
```

And it will delete `foo`. However I want to delete `bar` and `baz` as well. I tried doing:

```
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "foo" "bar" "baz")
```

and making this a list and passing it in, but it complains about the wrong number of arguments. How do I accomplish this? I'm assuming this is possible using this command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `DIRECTORY` option with the alternate command [set_property](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set_property.html).

```
set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY ADDITIONAL_MAKE_CLEAN_FILES "foo" "bar" "baz")
```

Comment: Why does this work and not `set_directory_properties`?

Comment: `set_directory_properties` only allows for singular values, i.e. `set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES prop1 value1 prop2 value2)`